# TypeError while using Behat/Mink

Tags: php, behat, mink

The execution of the following code:

```
<?php

class InheritedFeatureContext extends Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext
{
    /**
     *Simulates hovering over a link
     *
     * @When /^I mouse over "([^"]*)"$/
     */
        public function iMouseOver($link)
        {
        $this->getSession()->getPage()->findLink($link)->mouseOver();
        }

    /**
     *Waits for the appearence of a drop down
     *
     * @Then /^I wait for the suggestion box to appear$/
     */
    public function iWaitForTheSuggestionBoxToAppear()
    {
        $this->getSession()->wait(5000, "$('.suggestions-results').children().length > 0");
    }
}
```

produces the error msg:

```
  TypeError: $ is not a function
```

in reference to:

```
$this->getSession()->wait(5000, "$('.suggestions-results').children().length > 0");
```

This code worked just fine previously. Any ideas

Context: This is part of a Behat/Mink feature

Comment: This should not need jQuery it is inheritance from Mink context.

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't include jQuery but you're trying to use it here:

```
$this->getSession()->wait(5000, "$('.suggestions-results').children().length > 0");
```

wait() method accepts javascript as its second argument. It waits for script to evaluate to true (for maximum number of miliseconds passed as a first argument).

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong this code is from behat mink example at site.

That example was using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki as base url and wikipedia does have jquery script attached with it. In your case have you checked your url location if it contains jquery or not

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you did not include jQuery.

If you do not want to add jQuery to your project just to support this Mink test, try changing your line to the following which will accomplish the same thing, but doesn't use jQuery:

`$this->getSession()->wait(5000, "document.querySelector('.suggestions-results').children.length > 0");`

Answer (score -1):

This works for me using jQuery instead of the the `$` shortcut:

```
$this->getSession()->wait(5000, "jQuery('.suggestions-results').children().length > 0");
```

Comment: Isn't this the exact same answer as brianrhea?

Comment: No. brianrea's answer doesn't use jQuery. This one does.